# How to disable the list-item which I've just clicked in an listview in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I've an activity in which I'm showing a list of students(name, roll number) in listview. 
It's actually to take attendance of students.  The user clicks on listview item(which displays his name) and then a dialogbox is opened in which the student enters his password and clicks on "present" button. Whenever the student clicks on "present" button I want to disable the listview item which was just clicked. That means if the student clicks on the same listview item again then he shouldn't be allowed to do so.
It would be an immense pleasure if someone helps me out here to disable the list view item.

This is the studname_listview.xml. This is the content of the listview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rollnumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="11093"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="roger"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lastname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="federrer"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the student_main.xml : This is the where the listview is there. On this listview I'm showing the contents of studmain_list_xml

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/id_student_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm posting the onclicklistener code I've successfully written so far which does everything I mentioned except the disabling of listview item.

this is the DisplayStudentActivity.java which gets called every time I click on any item of listview named "id_student_list".

```
public class DisplayStudentActivity extends Activity   {

private ListView listView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.student_main);  // listview file name

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> Items = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

 // Adding Items to ListView
   OverlordSimpleAdapter adapter = new OverlordSimpleAdapter(this, Items,
            R.layout.studname_listview, new String[] { "firstname", "lastname", "roll" },
          new int[] {R.id.firstname, R.id.lastname, R.id.rollnumber });

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.id_student_list);   // list view cha naav
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            { 
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(DisplayStudentActivity.this);
                alertDialog.setTitle(db_fname + " "+ db_lname);
                alertDialog.setMessage("Enter your Password");

                final EditText input = new EditText(DisplayStudentActivity.this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                  input.setLayoutParams(lp);
                  alertDialog.setView(input);

                 alertDialog.setPositiveButton("PRESENT",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
// When the control comes here i.e. "PRESENT" button is clicked, I wish to
 //disable only the item of listview which was clicked to reach here.
//an anyone come up with a working code?
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                    {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.show();
            }

        // inside this 
        }
        });

    db.close();
}





public class OverlordSimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

public OverlordSimpleAdapter(Context context,
        List<? extends Map<String, String>> Items, int resource, String[] from,
        int[] to) {
    super(context, Items, resource, from, to);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
   boolean wasClicked =listView.isItemChecked(position);
    view.setEnabled(!wasClicked);
    return view; 
}
```

}
}

Comment: just setClickable as false for the respective layout.

Comment: I have a hint: to use 
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
  return false;
}
and pass the position of the listview item clicked to this above function. But how to get the position of the item clicked ??

Comment: you will get the position of item in getView.

Comment: @itsrajesh4uguys: where to write setClickable as false in the code??
in the else part of the onclick of "present" button ??

Comment: That's not a very good solution, you'll have issues if you have a list longer then the screen, and you scroll up or down. I'm guessing the wrong students would become disabled

Comment: solution to this problem? @marmor

Comment: my class is not a subclass of ArrayAdapter. So can't override isEnabled() method..anyway to do this using Activity as parent class?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a ListView feature called `setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);` 
(android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" in xml)

See here: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setChoiceMode(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setChoiceMode%28int%29)

This will store a state selected/not selected per list item, and will properly refresh it when scrolling the list.

Then in your adapter's `getView` call `setEnabled` on that item according to the `isItemChecked(int)` state of that item.

**EDIT:**

```
@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    boolean wasClicked = mListView.isItemChecked(position);
    view.setEnabled(!wasClicked);
    return view; 
}
```

Comment: the thing is that I'm not using a custom adapter.
I'm using the simpleAdapter class. So it's kinda confusing with errors such as view not found and listview id should be @+id:list

Comment: Then I think you'll have to extend SimpleAdapter to support this, just override getView and after calling the super, make the view enabled/disabled per its selected state.

Comment: is isItemChecked(int) our method or auto-generated method?
Coz it's giving an error "the method isItemChecked(int) is undefined for the type MySimpleAdapter"

Comment: check the edited question. Any changes in that, I should make??

Comment: i think you just need to add setItemChecked(position, true) in the onClick of the positive button